# Is there shorthand conditional syntax in swift?

Tags: swift

Is this the shortest way to write this in swift?

```
if currentStep == .confirmSignInAttempt1 || currentStep == .confirmSignInAttempt2 || currentStep == .confirmSignInAttempt3
```

Comment: How many different cases are there?

Comment: I would use an array and `contains`. Or a switch with a compound case.

Comment: array.contains written inline is ok but it might be clearer to extend the enum with a computed Bool property so you can write an expression where the logic is obvious: e.g. "if currentStep.isConfirmSignInFlow"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
if [.confirmSignInAttempt1,.confirmSignInAttempt2,.confirmSignInAttempt3].contains(currentStep)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom operator like:

```
if currentStep =|| [.confirmSignInAttempt1, .confirmSignInAttempt2, .confirmSignInAttempt3] { ... }
```

using a simple infix operator implementation

```
infix operator =||
func =||<T: Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: [T]) -> Bool { rhs.contains(lhs) }
```